# Conjugates of a partition $n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations, combinatorial-game-theory, combinatorial-proofs

Is there any easiest way finding of conjugate of a partition $n$ (Except using Ferrers diagram)?

e.g I can find the conjugate of a partition $a=[4,4,1]$ using Ferrers diagram, and I obtain $a^*=[3,2,2,2]$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&****    \ \ \    &***\\
&****   \to   \ &*\,*\\
&*       \ \     &*\,*\\
&             &*\,*
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

Given a partition $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)$, then
$$
(\lambda^*)_i=\# \{j:\lambda_j\ge i\}
$$
In your example,

- There are $3$ entries of $[4,4,1]$ which are $1$ or more,
- There are $2$ entries of $[4,4,1]$ which are $2$ or more,
- There are $2$ entries of $[4,4,1]$ which are $3$ or more,
- There are $2$ entries of $[4,4,1]$ which are $4$ or more,

so $a^*=[3,2,2,2]$.

Comment: Ow thank you very much !!!

Comment: Happy to help. By the way, it is considered courteous on stack exchange sites to click the green checkmark next to an answer if it completely answers your question.